# Facebook Debugger Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped

Tags: facebook

I have problem with shearing things on facebook when I try to some links it won't shere image description, etc...:

```
http://filmarker.com/?p=425
```

Also I tried my site on debugger but get this:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

Anyone can help, thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, when I run that URL through the debugger, I get _“Errors That Must Be Fixed: More Than One OG URL Specified – Object at URL 'http://filmarker.com/?p=425' of type 'article' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: http://filmarker.com/?p=425, http://filmarker.com/?p=425.”_